# Use ODC in Power Query (Get & Transform) Excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2013, powerquery

I have an ODC file hosted in a SharePoint Data Connection Library. Can I use this file to connect to the database in Power Query? 
I've successfully used the ODC when using "Get External Data" - but can't see how to use it within Power Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching it looks like it's not possible to use and ODC with Power Query/Get and Transform: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8b2341e-77cd-4744-aece-50be9e46061b/how-tp-connect-a-odc-file-in-sharepoint-2013-data-connections-library?forum=powerquery